# Firebase doesn't render React components

Tags: reactjs, firebase, webpack

I'm using react and firebase to build an app. I'm new to both.
My react works fine. But whenever I enter 'firebase serve --only hosting' in my command line, it deploys the local server but it doesn't show any components but only a blank page.
I've tried to figure out how to make it work but I can't find a way. Can anyone enlighten me please? Here is my code.

firebase.json

```
{
"hosting": {
  "public": "./public",
  "headers": [{
    "source" : "**/*.@(js|html)",
    "headers" : [ {
      "key" : "Cache-Control",
      "value" : "max-age=0"
    } ]
  }]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "homepage": ".",
  "name": "where_is_waldo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "firebase": "^9.9.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
"extends": [
  "react-app",
  "react-app/jest"
]
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirebaseConfig } from './firebase-config.js';
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <div>hi
    </div>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
reportWebVitals();
const firebaseAppConfig = getFirebaseConfig();
initializeApp(firebaseAppConfig);
```

/public/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
      <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" /> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
  name="description"
  content="Web site created using create-react-app"
/>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
<!--

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico",     
-->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
  This HTML file is a template.
  If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

  You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
  The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

  To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
  To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
-->
    <!-- <script src="scripts/main.js"></script> -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, why `public` if it should be `build`? public/index.html is just a raw template that will be used by react to inject scripts and all that should go to /build directory. Look closer to the comments in the html file you added. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-deploy-react-project-on-firebase/

Comment: @SergeySosunov hi.. this was the problem. thank you very much.